# Estimate shipping delivery date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would would be very grateful if someone can help me out with this.

I am looking to create add some html/js to my page so that once a customer puts their country in the drop down menu and clicks submit, produces an estimated delivery date.

Comment: What sort of structure do you have for the shipping dates? Do you break it down by land, sea, air and express or standard shipping?

Comment: Thank you for the response, I only need these options: Free Shipping and Express Shipping. And also a drop down with all countries. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use a map engine (like Google Maps API or Nokia Here) and calculate the distance. But this is very complex and in most situation over-sized.

I did a [country-code](http://www.janhommes.de/laenderliste/) list once and you can use this to archive what you want. Just use the JSON and add a new option `distance` to it. Then you just have to add it to a select:

```
$(function() {
    var countrycodes=[
        {"image":"ae.png","nameEN":"United Arab Emirates","code":"AE","distance":2},
        {"image":"us.png","nameEN":"United States","code":"US","distance":1},
        {"image":"vn.png","nameEN":"Viet Nam","code":"VN","distance":4},
        {"image":"cn.png","nameEN":"China","code":"CN","distance":3}
    ];

  $(countrycodes).each(function(i,value) {
    $("#SendingCountry").append("<option value=" + value.distance + ">"+ value.nameEN +"</option");
  });
  $("#calculate").click(function() {
     var result=$("#SendingCountry").val()*$("#SendingType").val();
     $("#result").text("Your order will be shipped within "+result+" day.");
  });
});
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r3RKq/4/) for details.

Comment: Brilliant thanks, how do i get the date today and add the days shipping to it for the result please?

Comment: The js-date functions are very limited. I'm using [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) framework and `Date.today().add(3)` for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Within the Country list I would format the

```
<select name="countries">
<option value='AA|3|1'>Somewhere</option>
<option value='AB|9|6'>Someplace</option>
</select>
```

Then in the JavaScript:

```
country = document.forms['f1'].elements['countries'].value;
prices = country.split('|');
prices[1] += 60 * 60 * 24;
prices[2] += 60 * 60 * 24;
today = new Date();
FreeShippingDate = today + prices[1];
ExpressShippingDate = today + price[2];
```

Hope this helps